# ANN - Velocity Initialization

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent, momentum

While trying to implement neural network training algorithms, I came across different concepts, including that of **Gradient descent** which tries to mimic a ball rolling down a hill, and of **velocity** and **momentum** to better model the rolling ball.

I initialized my `weights`, `weight_deltas`, and `weight_velocities` thus:

```
sizes = [2, 3, 1]
momentum_coefficient = 0.5    
weights = [ 2 * np.random.random((a, b)) - 1 for a, b in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:]) ]
weight_velocities = [ np.ones(w.shape) for w in weights ]
weight_deltas = [ np.zeros(w.shape) for w in weights ]
```

After calculating the deltas (derivative of the cost function with respect to the weights, I [updated](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html) the weights thus:

```
for l in xrange(sizes - 1):
    weight_velocities[l] = (momentum_factor * weight_velocities[l]) - weight_deltas[l]
    weights[l] += weight_velocities[l]
```

I used `np.zeros` to initialise my velocities, and I was able to get up to **80%** accuracy (*for a particular dataset*). But when I initialised with `np.ones`, I could not get up to **20%** accuracy. I've been using `ones`, but I can't figure out why `zeros` does work. And there's also the `random` method from `numpy`.

What's the recommended approach to initialise the `weight_velocities`?
Notice that I intentionally excluded the biases units, and the learning rate, and I'm `import`ing `numpy as np`.